# mvc 5 c# html color individual characters of string

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-treeview

In c# , I am trying to set font for individual characters of string.

Below is my code that I use with Kendo Grid to display tree node text which displays some count in brackets.

Example Customer1(**20**). Here I want to bold and color count.

```
 Name = EmpDb.Description + ((EmpDb.Cust.Count() > 0) ? "(" : "") +
                              ((EmpDb.Cust.Count() > 0) ? EmpDb.Cust.Count().ToString() : "") +
                             ((EmpDb.Cust.Count() > 0) ? ")" : "")
```

I tried below to bold, but it did not work and I got html tags in string.

```
 Name = EmpDb.Description + ((EmpDb.Cust.Count() > 0) ? "(<b>" : "") +
                              ((EmpDb.Cust.Count() > 0) ? EmpDb.Cust.Count().ToString() : "") +
                             ((EmpDb.Cust.Count() > 0) ? "</b>)" : "")
```

Thank you.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @Cleiton sorry what version are you talking? Visual Studio 2013, MVC5 , latest Telerik Kendo.